# Turn off split view for iPhone (all sizes), but retain split view for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, splitview

1.) We have a universal iOS app that incorporates split view and slide-over for iPad.  Just right.  For iPhone, on the other hand, we do not want to use these features.

2.) Split view does not appear for smaller iPhones, even in landscape, which is the desired behavior.  Just right, again. However, larger iPhones in landscape mode do by default, utilize split view, which is not the desired behavior.

3.) Split view on larger iPhones can be disabled at the user level(iOS 14): settings -> display and brightness -> view and select "Zoom".  That does achieve the intended result.  However, user may not find that feature desirable for all of their apps across their device.  It also requires a certain level of user sophistication to figure this out.  For these reasons, that is not a viable solution.

4.) There is an info.plist option called UIRequiresFullScreen, which achieves the intended result for iPhone, however it also disables split screen and slide-over for iPad, which is not the intended result.  We want this only to apply to iPhone. That is therefore not a viable solution either.

Seems there is likely a simple solution to the problem of turning off split view for larger iPhones for a universal iOS app, so the larger iPhones function just like the smaller iPhones.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think it's a "feature" of the OS - meaning, you cannot shut it off via code. Split view is not the same thing as using a `UISplitViewController`. Not even close. Here's my question - why do you desire to turn off an OS feature for iPhone only? (And if your answer involves your app's UI, then why aren't you using a more "adaptive" layout?)

Comment: In your delegate you can test that plataform type (iPhone or iPad) and set the storyboard use. IDK about SwiftUI and IDK if this is resolve your problem

Comment: Answer to dfd: Agree, the issue is about UISplitViewController.  The main point of your answer does indeed point us in the direction of the correct approach. See solution below.  Thanks for thinking about this!

Answer (score 0):

Responder dfd helped steer our thinking back on the right track.  The solution is not to try to remove the iPhone splitViewController feature of iOS, but as dfd pointed out, we should embrace the feature.  Thinking in splitViewController mode, rather than trying to force the larger iPhone to be a smaller iPhone, the behavior we are looking for in landscape view on larger iPhones is:

splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden

Calling this preferredDisplayMode on rotation on iPhone provides just the solution we were looking for.    Thanks to all who took the time to review our question!